# Probability of placing two particles in six boxes

Tags: probability

I am studying Probability in this semester. I got a problem sets and am trying solving it. Among the sets, I don't know how to approach this problem, even I cannot exactly understand what the question means.

> Place at random two particles in six boxes. Find the probability *p*
> that the particles will be found in two preselected boxes (one in each
> box) under the following three circumstances:
>
> 1. The particles are distinct and all alternatives are possible.
> 2. The particles cannot be distinguished and all alternatives are possible.
> 3. The particles cannot be distinguished and at most one particle is allowed in a box.

First of all, what do you think "particles will be found in two preselected boxes (one in each box)" means? Do you think it allows the two particles can be in the same box?

And, how about "alternatives"? I cannot get any sense of this.

Comment: In Q3 two particles can never be in the same box, so presumably it is possible in Q1 and Q2.  Meanwhile Q2 is dubious from a practical point of view, but means that Particle A in box X and Particle B in box Y cannot be distinguished form Particle B in box X and Particle A in box Y, so are treated as the same event

Comment: The prelude to the three parts clearly says "...that the particles will be found in two preselected boxes **(one in each box)**..." [emphasis mine] and should therefore apply to all parts

Comment: So the *favorable* arrangements for each part will have only one particle per box, whereas the total arrangements may have $2$ per box except for part three. Can you now handle it  ?

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*

The fact that you can *preselect boxes* implies that the boxes are distinct, so the $3$ problems are

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline 
Part & particles & boxes & favorable\; lt./box & total\; lt./box \\ \hline
1 & distinct & distinct & \leq 1 & none \\ \hline
2 & identical & distinct & \leq 1 & none \\ \hline
3 & identical & distinct & \leq 1 & \leq 1 \\ \hline  \end{array}$

Look up the [twelvefold way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way)

Answer (score -2):

Now, I understand what "alternatives" means. It means all possible cases. For instance in the problem, all alternatives of putting two distinct particles into six boxes is like this:

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ab | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| a | b | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| a | 0 | b | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| a | 0 | 0 | b | 0 | 0 |
| a | 0 | 0 | 0 | b | 0 |
| a | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | b |
| b | a | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | ab | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | a | b | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | a | 0 | b | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | a | 0 | 0 | b | 0 |
| 0 | a | 0 | 0 | 0 | b |
| b | 0 | a | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | b | a | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | ab | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | a | b | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | a | 0 | b | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | a | 0 | 0 | b |
| b | 0 | 0 | a | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | b | 0 | a | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | b | a | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | ab | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | a | b | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | a | 0 | b |
| b | 0 | 0 | 0 | a | 0 |
| 0 | b | 0 | 0 | a | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | b | 0 | a | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | b | a | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | ab | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | a | b |
| b | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | a |
| 0 | b | 0 | 0 | 0 | a |
| 0 | 0 | b | 0 | 0 | a |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | b | 0 | a |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | b | a |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | ab |

Here, table columns indicate box index, and rows indicate the possible case.

For the first sub-problem, the number of alternatives are 6*6=36 as we see the above table. Among them, the number of cases where the two particles are in the two preselected boxes (one box for each particle) is 2 (just select two boxes, e.g., 1 and 2, and count the numbers of particles there, e.g., case 1 is a in box 1 and b in box 2, and case 2 is a in the box 2 and b in the box 1). So, the probability is $2/36=1/18$.

We need another approach for the second sub-problem because particles are indistinguishable and boxes are also indistinguishable. We can think for this as arranging particles and **box walls** together.

[example of arranging particles and box walls together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXfpz.png)
(I borrow this image from https://ece307.cankaya.edu.tr/uploads/files/solution-manual.pdf)

Since boxes are not distinct among them and particles are not distinct among them, so the number of possible cases is: $((6-1)+2)!/(6-1)!2!$.

Here, $(6-1)!$ is permutation of 5 box walls (we only need 5 walls to make 6 boxes) and $2!$ is permutation of 2 particles. $((6-1)+2)!$ is permutations of 5 box walls and 2 particles. Then, the probability is its reciprocal number because there is just one case that particles are in the preselected boxes. ==> $(6-1)!2!/((6-1)+2)!$

The third sub-problem does not allow that particles are in the same box. In this case, we simply select two boxes to put the particles: ${}_6 \mathrm{ C }_2 = 6!/4!2! = 15$. Likewise the second sub-problem, there is just one case that particles are in the preselected boxes, so the result is $1/15$.

Helpful materials:

- Problem 4-34 (24p.) https://ece307.cankaya.edu.tr/uploads/files/solution-manual.pdf
- Problem 8 (3p.) https://webspace.clarkson.edu/projects/fluidflow/public_html/courses/me529/downloads/HW/hw1-Hints.pdf

## P.S.

Thank you @Taladris and @InanimateBeing for your thoughtful comment!

Comment: It is ok to answer your own question here, but you should quote the solution rather than simply giving a link, since the target of the link may disappear anytime.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful comments. I will rewrite this answer.

Comment: @Taladris No, self-answers are only OK in specific situations : 1. The question has been solved in the mean time by the author 2. The author established an important partial result. Minor improvements or changes should be done by editing the question.

Comment: @Peter, I lead the solution by my self just referring to the helpful links. Is my updated answer insufficient to be self-answers? Can you check, please?